# How to check if a system of linear inequalities is solvable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have the variables $x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}$ and the following relations:
$$x_{1}\rho_{1}x_{2}$$ 
$$x_{2}\rho_{2}x_{3}$$
$$...$$
$$x_{n-1}\rho_{n-1}x_{n},$$

where the relations $\rho_{i}\in[=,<,>]$ are known. How to check if the system of inequalities above are consistent or not?

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe the system, it is always solvable, and one solution is given by:

$$x_1=0\\
x_{k+1} = \begin{cases}x_k & \text{ if } \rho_{k} = "="\\
x_k+1 &  \text{ if } \rho_{k} = "<"\\
x_k-1 &  \text{ if } \rho_{k} = ">"\end{cases}$$

---

You can also see that you could take any tuple $(a_1,a_2\dots a_{n-1})$ of $n-1$ positive numbers, where $a_k=0$ if $\rho_{k-1}="="$, and define

$$x_1=a_1\\
x_{k+1} = \begin{cases}x_k & \text{ if } \rho_{k} = "="\\
x_k+a_{k+1} &  \text{ if } \rho_{k} = "<"\\
x_k-a_{k+1} &  \text{ if } \rho_{k} = ">"\end{cases}$$

to get an infinite set of possible solutions.